# php unsuccessful while loop within prepared statements

Tags: php, while-loop, prepared-statement, prepare

code below is a part of my `sitemap.xml` file. My aim is to write the last modified date of my approved articles. There are 2 possibilities for this data.

1. If article has no approved comment, then `lastmod` is the approval
   date of the article.
2. If article has at least 1 approved comment, then `lastmod` is the
   approval date of the last approved comment.

Errors in my output are:

1. There are some articles in my db that has no comments but also these commentless articles get the approval date of last comment of some other articles. As a result since I have some comments which are approved today, all those commentless articles' lastmode is date of today. but these articles are quite old.
2. `$newsql` in my 2nd while loop prints **"newstmt prepare error"** on
   screen, so `if ($newstmt = $connection->prepare($newsql))` part doesn't work

Can you please correct me?

Thank you, best regards

### code

```
<?php       
//if spesific article is approved then its last modification date = approval date of article
//if spesific article has approved comment(s), then modification date = approval date of its last comment
$sql = "SELECT col_author, col_title, col_approvaldate FROM articles WHERE col_status = ? ORDER by col_approvaldate DESC";

if ($stmt = $connection->prepare($sql)) 
{
    /* bind parameters */
    $stmt -> bind_param("s", $bindparam1);
    
    /* assign value */
    $bindparam1 = 'approved';
    
    /* execute statement */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($author, $title, $articledate);

    /* fetch values */
    while ($stmt->fetch()) 
    {
        //if exist, get approved newest comment approval date
        $newsql = "SELECT col_approvaldate FROM comments WHERE col_status = ? AND col_for_author = ? AND col_for_title = ? ORDER by col_approvaldate DESC LIMIT 1";
        if ($newstmt = $connection->prepare($newsql))
        {
            /* bind parameters */
            $newstmt -> bind_param("sss", $ybindparam1, $ybindparam2, $ybindparam3);
            
            /* give values */
            $ybindparam1 = 'approved';
            $ybindparam2 = $author;
            $ybindparam3 = $title;
            
            /* execute statement */
            $newstmt->execute();

            /* bind result variables */
            $newstmt->bind_result($commentdate);
            
            /* fetch values */
            $biggerdate = '';
            
            while ($newstmt->fetch())
            {                   
                // is there any approved comment for this article?
                if (!is_null($commentdate))
                {$biggerdate = $commentdate;}
            }
            /* close statement */
            $newstmt->close();                  
        }
        else {echo 'newstmt prepare error';}
        
        //print the result
        echo '<url>'."\r\n";
        echo "\t".'<loc>'.root_folder.urlencode('articles').'/'.urlencode(space_to_dash($author)).'/'.urlencode(space_to_dash(no_punctuation($title))).'</loc>'."\r\n";             
        //if there is no approved comment for this article
        if ($biggerdate == '') 
        {
            $biggerdate = $articledate;
        }
        $datetime = new DateTime($biggerdate);
        $biggerdate = $datetime->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP');
        echo "\t".'<lastmod>'.$biggerdate.'</lastmod>'."\r\n";
        echo '</url>'."\r\n";

    }
    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
    
}
?>
```

Comment: What does SELECT col_approvaldate FROM comments WHERE col_status = ? AND col_for_author = ? AND col_for_title = ? ORDER by col_approvaldate DESC LIMIT 1   give you when executing directly to the db (like phpMyAdmin or similar)

Comment: Hey, you're not linking comments to articles using article id? really?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld it gave me syntax error. I tried exactly as you wrote but I am not used to directly use phpmyadmin query window.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yes, may be it's stupid way but I don't use id.

Comment: Print `$connection->error` along with the `newstmt prepare error` message, to see the reason for the error.

Comment: @Barmar result is: "newstmt prepare error : Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"

Comment: You should probably do this all as a single query with a JOIN, not nested queries and loops. Search SO for "mysql newest row per group".

Comment: OK since I don't know to use JOIN, I will study it by searching "mysql newest row per group". So I can't suddenly modify my code and  try it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How it have to be

1. You have to get your data using single query.
2. Comments have to be linked using article id
3. [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) instead of mysqli ought to be used

So, here you go:

```
$sql = "SELECT author, title, a.approvaldate, max(c.approvdate) biggerdate
        FROM articles a
        LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.article_id = a.id AND c.status='approved'
        WHERE a.status = 'approved' 
        GROUP BY a.id
        ORDER BY a.approvaldate DESC";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchall();
foreach ($data as $row) {
    extract($row);
    echo "<url>\r\n";
    echo "\t<loc>".root_folder.'articles';
    echo '/'.urlencode(space_to_dash($author));
    echo '/'.urlencode(space_to_dash(no_punctuation($title)))."</loc>\r\n";
    //if there is no approved comment for this article
    if (!$biggerdate) 
    {
        $biggerdate = $approvaldate;
    }
    $datetime = new DateTime($biggerdate);
    $biggerdate = $datetime->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP');
    echo "\t<lastmod>$biggerdate</lastmod>\r\n";
    echo "</url>\r\n";
}
```

it is of course not tested and apparently contains many errors but just to show you an ides.

First of all you have to make query work.
then make read linked PDO tag wiki and establish a connection.
Then fix all the errors and typos, if any

Comment: I'd study it in the way you said. But I want to ask that I don't have article id as foreign key in my comments table; so does it mean that I can't use your code even it was 100% correct?

Comment: you just have to have an article id in the articles table and corresponding article id in the comments table. that's all