# MySQL Select Newest Approval Date among article date & comment date

Tags: mysql, select, inner-join

My aim is to write the last modified date (`lastmod`) of my approved articles for my `sitemap.xml` file. There are 2 possibilities for this data.

1. If article has no approved comment, then lastmod is the approval
   date of the article.
2. If article has at least 1 approved comment, then lastmod is the
   approval date of the last approved comment of related article.

after asking [php unsuccessful while loop within prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155260/php-unsuccessful-while-loop-within-prepared-statements) question and reading answers, I decided

1. not to use loop within prepared for this case
2. add `col_article_id` column to my comments table which shows the
   related article's id in article table
3. and try to solve my case with a smarter mySQL query

I have 2 tables:

1. articles
2. comments (`comments.col_article_id` links the comment to the related
   article)

After I tried query below,

```
select tb_articles.col_approvaldate, tb_comments.col_approvaldate
from tb_articles, tb_comments
where tb_articles.col_status ='approved' AND tb_comments.col_status ='approved' AND tb_articles.col_id=tb_comments.col_article_id
```

my problems are:

1  - I need someway as if it was allowed in mysql syntax that `select max( tb_articles.col_approvaldate, tb_comments.col_approvaldate)`

2 - **If I have n approved articles without any approved comment and m approved articles with approved comment(s), then I should have n+m result rows with 1 column at each row. But currently, I have m rows with 2 columns at each row.**

So I'm aware that I'm terribly on wrong way.

I also searched "*mysql newest row per group*" keywords. But this the point I could arrived after all.

this is my 1st `join` experience. can you please correct me? best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do I understand correctly that `tb_comments` record for an article is created by default? This should not be the case - if there are no comments, there shouldn't be a record there. If there is, what is the default date you are putting in? NULL? Also `tb_comments.col_status` seems redundant to me - if you have `tb_comments.col_approvaldate` then it is approved on that date and you don't really need status at all.

This query is probably what would work for you (commented `AND` shouldn't change things if I understand your table structure properly):

```
SELECT 
    a.col_id AS 'article_id',
    IFNULL(MAX(c.col_approvaldate), a.col_approvaldate)
FROM 
    tb_articles a 
    LEFT JOIN tb_comments c ON a.col_id = c.col_article_id #AND c.col_status ='approved'
WHERE 
    a.col_status ='approved'
GROUP BY a.col_id
```

Comment: First of all, I tried the query in phpadmin sql window. Unfortunately, it gave me "#1054 - Unknown column 'tb_articles.col_status' in 'where clause'" message. I definitely have this column in related table. secondly, my logic is: author saves into tb_articles. at that time status = 'pending'. Then if editor approves, status become 'approved'.This means article is published. people writes comments then. Same logic works here also. 1st save means automatic pending. Then if editor approves comment status also become 'approved' and it's published. if status pending, approval date is null.

Comment: Edited the query - check it out now.

Comment: Thanks for help effort, best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select
    tb_articles.id,
    ifnull(
        max( tb_comments.col_approvaldate),
        tb_articles.col_approvaldate
    ) as last_approved
from tb_articles
left join tb_comments
    on tb_articles.col_id=tb_comments.col_article_id
    and tb_comments.col_status ='approved'
where tb_articles.col_status ='approved'
group by 1;
```

Comment: I tried the query in phpadmin sql window. Unfortunately, it gave me only 1 record. Title of the column is last_approved, and the only 1 record is the approval date of the newest comment in my site.

Comment: See edited answer. You can add more columns from tb_articles - if you do, add them to the group by too (by number like I have, or by name)

Comment: edited answer result is: dates works properly if an approved article has/have approved comment(s); however dates for approved articles without any comment come with NULL value. Thanks for help effort, best regards.

Comment: Must be that `greatest()` considers null to be grater than a value. I've edited the answer - see if that works for you (it should!).

Comment: with `max` command, query gives syntax error. I edited it as `greatest` and this time mysql message became: `#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ifnull'`; then I replaced `ifnull` with `coalesce` and query worked but result is same with my previous comment:dates works properly if an approved article has/have approved comment(s); however dates for approved articles without any comment come with NULL value. Thanks for help effort, best regards.

Comment: This answer works perfectly also. Thank you so much for your extra effort & wish to help. Best regards Bohemian. I liked your icon by the way :-)

Comment: `)` character just before `as last_approved` should be removed.BR

Comment: You are quite right. I have fixed it. Lets hope this last edit is the last :)